# Deleting files using DownloadURL in AngularFire2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Using AngularFire2 5.0.0-rc.6 and Angular 5.2.11 , is there any way to Delete a file from a Firebase storage Folder using the downloadURL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes of course. `AngularFireStorage` has a `storage` object on it with a method named `refFromURL` on it. You can call it with your Download URL. This will return an instance of type `firebase.storage.Reference` on which you can then call `delete`. This returns a `Promise<any>` which you can return if you want.

Try this:

```
constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }

....

delete(downloadUrl) {
  return this.storage.storage.refFromURL(downloadUrl).delete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! spent a huge time looking for an answer

Comment: Still works great in 2022. Angular 12 / Firebase 7